# What kind of spider is this? (Photo included)

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

We found this guy on the ceiling inside today. We live by Lake Erie in Ohio so we see a lot of large spiders, but this one looks different than most we encounter. It's was about the size of a quarter (~ 25 mm), and the abdomen was iridescent.

Comment: Not a spider person but I did find [this](https://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/pdf/commonly-encountered-pa-spiders) useful summary of commonly encountered Pennsylvania spiders, a few of which are similar-looking.

Comment: It looks to me like a false widow spider, Steatoda grossa. It would be helpful if you could find one in their web so I could see what its web looks like.